# Push Notification in non english languages

Tags: iphone, push-notification, non-english

I have implemented successfully this code:

[Does anyone know how to write an Apple Push Notification Provider in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020762/does-anyone-know-how-to-write-an-apple-push-notification-provider-in-c)

It works great. But I have a question, can anybody help me how to send non english messages like Hebrew Or Arabic?

If the string contains any non english characters, it is not sent.

Thank you

Comment: There's a difference between English and ASCII.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the solution.

The length was wrong. In the code we pass the length of the string before the counting. We should count it after the UTF encoding:

```
writer.Write((byte)0); //First byte of payload length; (big-endian first byte) 
enter code herebyte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
writer.Write((byte)b1.Length);     //payload length (big-endian second byte)
```

Comment: @Meir can you please tell me that how you manage those non English messages at application side means through Xcode? have you done any other language settings for application