# Push notification problem

Tags: iphone, ios4, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Im developing an iphone app with push notification service, **the problem that when i sent an non English language notification  the notification dose not appear on iphone screen but the Badge Number appear on the app icon and the sound for push notification played**, on the other hand  when i sent an English notification every thing going good.

i sent the notification via php service and the php can understand the non English language so where are the problem ?!!!

any help :)

Comment: when a application receives a notification, and a user clicks on it, the notification can be accessed by the application that received it. so may be you should try looking in to what your app receives. is the alert potion completely blank? and what is the encoding for the alert/message?

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that non-English characters can be sent via APNS.  I would focus on the php framework you are using.

Maybe this SO post can help: [Push Notification in non english languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111076/push-notification-in-non-english-languages).  Essentially, the payload length could be calculated incorrectly.