# IOS Push Notifications in Arabic using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ios, push-notification

I m sending push notification from C# in Arabic.

This is my code:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("اختبار").Replace("+", "%20")
```

When the app is open, it shows notification within app in Arabic, but if the app is hidden, the notification is displayed in notification screen with encode character like:

%d8%a7%d8%ae%d8%aa%d8%a8

Please give any suggestion.

Comment: Remove `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` it makes this `%something` symbols

Comment: But if remove HttpUtility.UrlEncode notification show only question marks like ????????????????????????????

Comment: You need to somehow change encoding

Comment: i m already try utf8 encode, utf32 encode but arabic characters not show

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020762/does-anyone-know-how-to-write-an-apple-push-notification-provider-in-c this and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111076/push-notification-in-non-english-languages maybe it will help

Comment: Refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34128014/ios-pushnotification-in-arabic-language