# IOS Pushnotification in Arabic language

Tags: c#, ios, asp.net

Please let me know how to send push notification in non-English language.

I am following [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/pandeypradip/apple-push-notification-using-Asp-Net/) for sending push notification. English push notifications are OK.

But when I am trying with non English language getting notification as `???????????????????`.

After searching in google getting suggestions to change the length in payload. Can any one help me out where to change size length in following method?

```
private static byte[] GeneratePayload(NotificationPayload payload)
    {
      try
      {
        //convert Devide token to HEX value.
        byte[] deviceToken = new byte[payload.DeviceToken.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < deviceToken.Length; i++)
            deviceToken[i] = byte.Parse(payload.DeviceToken.Substring(i * 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        // Command
        memoryStream.WriteByte(1); // Changed command Type 

        //Adding ID to Payload          
        memoryStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload.PayloadId.ToString()), 0, payload.PayloadId.ToString().Length);

        //Adding ExpiryDate to Payload
        int epoch = (int) (DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(300) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
        byte[] timeStamp = BitConverter.GetBytes(epoch);
        memoryStream.Write(timeStamp, 0, timeStamp.Length);

        byte[] tokenLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16) 32);
        Array.Reverse(tokenLength);
        // device token length
        memoryStream.Write(tokenLength, 0, 2);

        // Token
        memoryStream.Write(deviceToken, 0, 32);

      // String length
        string apnMessage = payload.ToJson();
        Logger.Info("Payload generated for " + payload.DeviceToken + " : " + apnMessage);

        byte[] apnMessageLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16) apnMessage.Length);
        Array.Reverse(apnMessageLength);

        // message length
        memoryStream.Write(apnMessageLength, 0, 2); 

        // Write the message
        memoryStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apnMessage), 0, apnMessage.Length);        
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Logger.Error("Unable to generate payload - " + ex.Message);
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1020762/does-anyone-know-how-to-write-an-apple-push-notification-provider-in-c) modified GeneratePayload method and I am able to send push notifications in any non english language.
Code as follows:

```
private static byte[] GeneratePayload(NotificationPayload payload)
    {
      try
      {
        //convert Devide token to HEX value.
        byte[] deviceToken = new byte[payload.DeviceToken.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < deviceToken.Length; i++)
            deviceToken[i] = byte.Parse(payload.DeviceToken.Substring(i * 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

        BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);

        writer.Write((byte)0);  //The command
        writer.Write((byte)0);  //The first byte of the deviceId length (big-endian first byte)
        writer.Write((byte)32); //The deviceId length (big-endian second byte)

        writer.Write(deviceToken);       

        writer.Write((byte)0); //First byte of payload length; (big-endian first byte)        
        byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload.ToJson());
        writer.Write((byte)b1.Length);       
        writer.Write(b1);
        writer.Flush();

        byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();

        // Command
        memoryStream.WriteByte(1); // Changed command Type 

        //Adding ID to Payload                  
        memoryStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload.PayloadId.ToString()), 0, payload.PayloadId.ToString().Length);

        //Adding ExpiryDate to Payload
        int epoch = (int) (DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(300) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds;
        byte[] timeStamp = BitConverter.GetBytes(epoch);
        memoryStream.Write(timeStamp, 0, timeStamp.Length);

        byte[] tokenLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16) 32); 
        Array.Reverse(tokenLength);
        // device token length
        memoryStream.Write(tokenLength, 0, 2);

        // Token
        memoryStream.Write(deviceToken, 0, 32);

      // String length
        string apnMessage = payload.ToJson(); 
        Logger.Info("Payload generated for " + payload.DeviceToken + " : " + apnMessage);

        byte[] apnMessageLength = BitConverter.GetBytes((Int16)apnMessage.Length);
        Array.Reverse(apnMessageLength);

        // message length
        memoryStream.Write(apnMessageLength, 0, 2); 

        // Write the message        
        memoryStream.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(apnMessage), 0, apnMessage.Length);
        return array;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        Logger.Error("Unable to generate payload - " + ex.Message);
        return null;
      }
    }
```